# Error compiling Oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written this stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_EMPLOYEE 
(
  F_FNAME IN VARCHAR2 
, L_NAME IN VARCHAR2 
, EMAIL IN VARCHAR2 
, jobid IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'SA_REP' 
, MGR IN employees.manager_id%type DEFAULT 145 
, SAL IN employees.salary%type DEFAULT 1000 
, COMM IN EMPLOYEES.COMMISSION_PCT%type DEFAULT 0 
, DEPTID IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 30 
, HIRE_DATE IN DATE 
) 
AS 
BEGIN
insert into EMPLOYEES(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,hire_date,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
values
(employees_seq.nextval,f_name,l_name,email,HIRE_DATE,sal,comm,mgr,deptid);

END ADD_EMPLOYEE;
```

It gives the message

```
sql statement ignored.
columns not allowed here.
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  When writing a title, please do not SHOUT.  And when writing a question, please remember to ask a question — don't leave the question to be inferred.  Does the error message include any extra positional information about where the error is?  Is the error message transcribed accurately?  Shouldn't there be an ORA#### error number associated with it too?

Comment: Note that `email` and `hire_date` are both variables and apparently column names — they might be the cause of some of your trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename parameters **email** and **hire_date**. 
Also, it is handy to name parameters as it's corresponding columns with additional prefix 'p_'. In your case:

- employee_id -> p_employee_id
- first_name -> p_first_name
- ...
- department_id-> p_department_id.

If you declare local variable, you can use 'v_' prefix.